# Is it good practice to develop python applications as packages

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

I'm developing a rather complex desktop application using wxPython framework. At this point, app already contains a dozens of modules: libraries, UI modules, util modules.

Project looks like this:

```
MyApp/
    __init__.py -- empty
    main.py
    util/
        __init__.py -- empty
    lib1/
        __init__.py
    lib2/
        __init__.py
    gui/
        __init__.py -- empty
        window1.py
```

Unfortunately with current project structure I cannot use absolute imports, because `python MyApp/main.py` will fail with error like `ImportError: No module named MyApp.gui`

To overcome this, I'd like to make MyApp an executable package:

```
my_app/
    __init__.py -- empty
    __main__.py
    util/
        __init__.py -- empty
    lib1/
        __init__.py
    lib2/
        __init__.py
    gui/
        __init__.py -- empty
        window1.py
```

Now application can be started using `python -m my_app`

Everything seems ok so far… but I am full of doubts, because no-one uses such approach. If you take a look at demo that comes with wxPython you'll see that it's mostly flat project.

I'm definitely not the smartest one therefore I'm missing something simple and obvious why no-one uses such approach.

Maybe I should just stick with subfolders or flat project structure? Maybe absolute imports don't worth such changes?

Comment: I definitely wouldn't call it `__main__.py` as the double underscore surround implies that it's special to Python in some way.

Comment: But the idea is to make package "executable". So you could start an app using `python -m MyApp`. Does it sound bad?

Comment: I really don't see why you'd want that. That kind of running is generally reserved for packages that serve as libraries and stand alone scripts (see ``timeit`` for an obvious example). It would be more normal just to have `myapp.py` which your users run normally.

Comment: But python does not allow you to easily organize your multi-module projects, because there is not easy way to import from subfolders -> you're forced to use packages. Then if app's root is not a package, cross-importing is pain.

Comment: You are right, I deleted my answer, as it being a package is the preferable choice here. That said, you seem pretty sure this was the right call, so I'm not sure why you posted the question?

Comment: @Lattyware, please, take a look at the updated question.

Answer (score 2):

If I were you, I would look at some of the wxPython applications that are out there and see how they do it.

- [Editra](http://editra.org/) - a text file editor + more
- [Chandler project](http://chandlerproject.org/)
- [Phatch](http://www.phatch.org/)

Or even the wxPython demo package.

Comment: I've taken a look, but wxPython use the old project and changes it uses legacy techniques are high.

Answer (score 2):

Putting most of it in a package namespace is the best way to go, since you can also take advantage of byte-code caching and setuptools/Distribute can easily install it. Then you just provide a simple top-level script to load the main module and run it.

Something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
from MyApp import main

main.main(sys.argv)
```

Just name that something like `myapp` and install in /usr/local/bin (or somewhere on PATH).  All it does is import the main module and run the main function (or class).

Comment: Maybe it's simpler to just add `__main__.py` then run package using python -m MyApp? I don't understand why adding custom main script (which is the only entry point) is preferred over __main__.py

Comment: @Kentzo That works too, on newer (2.7) Python. But there are still older Python's out there. Also, what would you rather have your users run "myapp", or "python -m MyApp" ? You could wrap that latter in a shell script, but why bother?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out which approach is better to stick with it. Otherwise I'll stickle every time I start new wxPython project.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to understand why it's a good thing to have it under a single package. So I think I'll just go over this briefly:

1. You get to organize your project better. If you have multiple modules responsible for different things, you don't fear having a conflict with some other library. So it will basically act as a simple namespace.
2. You get the benefit of updating via easy_install or whatever. I'm not sure it's really a big plus though.
3. It can be easier to extend with plugins, whether voluntarily allowing them, or just leaving place for some tweaking on the user-side.

I'll just give you some examples which use this approach, I think mainly for the plugins approach:

- [Exaile](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~exaile-devel/exaile/trunk/files/head:/): music player, which allows you to add plugins through this structure, and notice also the gui is in a separate package. Not sure why, but it definitely makes the separation of UI (GTK, but does not matter) clear.
- I'll just advertise myself here :) [wxpos](http://code.google.com/p/wxpos/): it's one of my projects, if you want to take a look at my approach with wxPython as an example.

There are more than I can think of, I'm sure I've seen it somewhere else too.